# Open GUI Java file with Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I created a .java file with NetBeans 6.9 GUI builder. Then I transfered the file to my LInux machine and tried to open it up and continue editing with the GUI builder.

But I notice that I don't have the option for the GUI builder anymore. As in be able to drag and drop buttons and all that.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Did you just transfer the Java file? Or did you export it as a Jar and then import the Jar into NetBeans. You must do the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Swing classes depend on two files: The `.java` source file and a `.form` file. You need both to be able to keep working in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Swing classes depend on two files: The .java source file and a .form file. these two files should be same name,same path. then double click the .java file , you can switch it between 'source' and design.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options:

1. Learn to handcode GUI's. JFrame is super simple! [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUdIAgJ7JKo) is a very nice tutorial.
2. Re-Install NetBeans. This should reset everything to the default setting. But, it will keep your projects intact.